# Object Variable or With Block Variable not Set - Macro VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an error

> Object Variable or With Block Variable not Set

at `Set lineProject = c.Row`
when using the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim pptFile As Object

Dim ppres As PowerPoint.Presentation

Path = "\\FSCFFACT\Activites\CFF DOMO GP ACT\Tableau de Bord\" 

Set pptFile = CreateObject("Powerpoint.application")

If ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then

        CODOMO.Hide

        Libelle = ComboBox1.Value

        lastline = Worksheets("Projets").Cells(Worksheets("Projets").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        Set c = Worksheets("Projets").Range("B10:B" & lastline).Find(Libelle)

        Set lineProject = c.Row

        pptFile.Presentations.Open (Path & "Modèle CODOMO.pptx")

        Set pppres = pptFile.ActivePresentation

    Else
        ...        
    End If
End Sub
```

I used he same lines in another macros, to find the ligne of a project using the **Libelle**.

Thanks for telling what's wrong.

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: I get this error :
Object Variable or With Block Variable not Set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this the line where you got the error

```
Set c = Worksheets("Projets").Range("B10:B" & lastline).Find(Libellé)
```

With `.Find(Libellé)`  do you mean `Libellé` as string or as variable?

If …

- string then use `.Find("Libellé")`
- variable then `.Find(Libelle)` would be correct.
  Because your variable name is `Libelle = ComboBox1.Value`

Make sure you use `Option Explicit` to avoid wrong typed variable names.
And declare **all** your variables before use:

```
Dim Libelle As String
Libelle = ComboBox1.Value
```

Comment: The error comes in this line :
Set ligneProjet = c.Row

Comment: The error occurs because nothing was found (one line before). Did you read my answer above? This should solve your issue. Use `Option Explicit` to avoid such errors in the future.

Comment: Yes of course. I mean Libelle as a variable not as string.
Ive added the declaration ligne on : Dim Libelle as String, but i still have the same error

Comment: Did you use `Option Explicit` as I recommended? No, obviously you didn't. If you did you would have seen that your variable is `Libelle` but you used `Libellé`. The accent makes it a completely different variable! **I again hardly recommend to use Option Explicit to avoid such typos!** I don't recommend this just for fun, I recommended it because this is necessary to show your issue and prevents you from such issues in the future.

Comment: If the error is still the same after using `Option Explicit` then the issue is that the value of `Libelle = ComboBox1.Value` is not found in the range you searched.

Comment: Yes i('ve setted it. Wen looking at the code i've poser, i've seen that i put an accent were i souldn't.
There is no accent anywhere. And when i look n debugging, i see that the : **Set c = Worksheets("Projets").Range("B10:B" & lastline).Find(Libellé)** returs **nothing**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166232/discussion-between-n-yaici-and-p).

Comment: In your comment there is again an accent :) If you are not very precisely we are not able to fix your issues. Try and catch if the value was found or not with `If c Is Nothing Then MsgBox "'" & Libelle & "' was not found. Aborting now …": Exit Sub` right one line  after `Set c = …`

Comment: Yes sorry. I've got the error : 'Project name' was not found.

Comment: Thank you @peh !!

Comment: That means that you searched for `Project name` but it was not found in the range.

Comment: Yes but now i'm searching with **MatchCase** option on **Find** function. Thank you again